# Time Consuming UI Update Task in Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

This is not another question about how to handle background tasks in Swing (I hope so).

I'm using a third party non-open-source library for which I don't have the source code.
This library provides an "XMLBuilder" which takes a data object and a template object, and then build some UI inside an object extending JComponent.

Because this "build method" needs to update the JComponent it needs to run on the EDT.
Problem is I am giving it a pretty big set of data to work with, which takes significant time (can be over 20s). During this time my whole application is frozen.

What can I do about this ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `SwingWorker`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the third-party library may be doing a large amount of non-ui work on the EDT.

If so, there's not much that you can do about it other than either asking the vendor to fix it, or if they won't/can't, getting rid of the library and re-implementing it in way that respects the EDT.

Comment: That's what I thought, I don't think asking the vendor to fix it is an option I'll have to do some custom optimization then.